# React native >= 0.60 autolinking react-native-google-cast

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, react-native-google-cast

[image]

I'm trying to install [react-native-google-cast](https://react-native-google-cast.github.io/docs/getting-started/installation#android).

I performed the steps described.

In the documentation it says:

```
No additional setup needed thanks to autolinking.
```

Once I ran the `react-native link` command and it did the linking.

If I try it doesn't work, so I don't have to run any commands?

As soon as I install the library it gives me the following error:

```
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'nptest'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/userName/Desktop/testApk/mks/android/build.gradle' (/Users/userName/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/e7l213puljy1f81zmlggf68ny).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'nptest'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/userName/Desktop/testApk/mks/android/build.gradle' (/Users/userName/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/e7l213puljy1f81zmlggf68ny).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    at makeError (/Users/userName/Desktop/testApk/mks/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/userName/Desktop/testApk/mks/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/userName/Desktop/testApk/mks/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/userName/Desktop/testApk/mks/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

If I try to remove the library after a few tries it works again.

If I put it back it doesn't work anymore.

If I go to see the `PackageList` file in `android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java`

I see this:

```
package com.facebook.react;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainPackageConfig;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

// @react-native-community/netinfo
import com.reactnativecommunity.netinfo.NetInfoPackage;
// react-native-gesture-handler
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
// react-native-safe-area-context
import com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext.SafeAreaContextPackage;
// react-native-screens
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
// react-native-vector-icons
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
// react-native-webview
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;

public class PackageList {
  private Application application;
  private ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost;
  private MainPackageConfig mConfig;

  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost) {
    this(reactNativeHost, null);
  }

  public PackageList(Application application) {
    this(application, null);
  }

  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost, MainPackageConfig config) {
    this.reactNativeHost = reactNativeHost;
    mConfig = config;
  }

  public PackageList(Application application, MainPackageConfig config) {
    this.reactNativeHost = null;
    this.application = application;
    mConfig = config;
  }

  private ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return this.reactNativeHost;
  }

  private Resources getResources() {
    return this.getApplication().getResources();
  }

  private Application getApplication() {
    if (this.reactNativeHost == null) return this.application;
    return this.reactNativeHost.getApplication();
  }

  private Context getApplicationContext() {
    return this.getApplication().getApplicationContext();
  }

  public ArrayList<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(mConfig),
      new NetInfoPackage(),
      new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
      new SafeAreaContextPackage(),
      new RNScreensPackage(),
      new VectorIconsPackage(),
      new RNCWebViewPackage()
    ));
  }
}
```

But I can't find the one from `react-native-google-cast`.

Do you think it has something to do with it?

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: `Unsupported class file major version 64` indicates java 20, if you run your commands from command line then check which version of java is used with 'java --version', also check JAVA_HOME

Comment: @marcinj: 
`openjdk 20.0.1 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: @marcinj: How do I check `JAVA_HOME` on macos and what exactly do I need to check?

Comment: @marcinj: if I run the following command: `java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home` i get `java.home = /Users/nameUser/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-20.0.1/Contents/Home`

Comment: @Abe: I do not understand what I have to do?

Comment: Sorry, typo in last comment. You should be using JDK 11. Check the docs for how to set it up. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&os=macos

Comment: How do I know which JDKs I have and which ones I'm using?

Comment: You should use the same JDK in command line as in Android Studio. I suggest using  JDK 17. Does your project compile in Android Studio?

Comment: @marcinj: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SpJp.png I don't compile with android studio, I use `yarn android` command.